# pass value to renderpartial in master page from user control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

Is it possible to have a master page that has a renderpartial it in and supply a value to be passed to that partial before it is rendered.

For example we have a common menu structure across our site, I would like to put this as a partial in the master page, the problem comes in that depending on what area in the page you are we need to set a value for the selected tab so it gets highlighted and you can see where you are.

Currently the render partial is on ever page and passes in a value for the selected tab, I would like this to be in the master page and just have some way to pass the value to the master page.

I have a feeling this might be possible with the changes introduced with razor but I'm not sure, in any case we are using asp.net mvc 2 (although I'm still interested in things that would apply to more recent versions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use RouteData property to get currently called page using the following:

```
ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]

// OR

ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
```

Either in the controller associated with the menu or in the view itself (if it's partial). Then you can filter the output upon the current route.